# Grafana Value Mapping an Array

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

So I'm using grafana to display some data in a table. So in my grafana table I have a column named 'request_types'. Its value is represented by an array such as

```
["all"], ["Music", "Film"], ...etc
```

What I'm trying to do is create value mappings in grafana to map the array to specific values. For example

```
["all"] -> "All"
["Artist", "Film"] -> Artist, Film
```

How can I achieve this in grafana? Is value mapping the only option I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order for me to achieve this I had to create a `custom data source plugin`. Basically my data source plugin makes an http request to retrieve Elasticsearch data. From there I can write some typescript to manipulate my data.